# UIImageView jumps around

Tags: ios, socket.io

I call this method every 0.2 seconds to send the UIImageView position via socket.io:

```
- (void)update {
     CGPoint touchLocation = blue.center;
     if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(touchLocation, lastLocation) && !isAnimating) {
         NSDictionary *json = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@(touchLocation.x), @"x", @(touchLocation.y), @"y", nil];
        [socketIO sendJSON:json];
        lastLocation = touchLocation;
    }
}
```

When the other device recieves this data, it's displayed as so:

```
- (void)socketIO:(SocketIO *)socket didReceiveEvent:(SocketIOPacket *)packet {
    int x = [[packet.name valueForKey:@"x"] intValue];
    int y = [[packet.name valueForKey:@"y"] intValue];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        [red setCenter:CGPointMake(x, y)];
    }];
}
```

Even though I animated the movement, the animation is very jittery/jumpy on the receiving side. I would send the raw data from `touchesMoved:` but I'm sending a lot of data. I've tried changing the update interval to 0.05 but I'm sending 100 packets every 5 seconds *per player*. Is this even a lot? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You might want to try using the option to start animations in-flight, otherwise this will cancel the previous animation, jump it to the end state, and apply the new one. Also, I'm unfamiliar with socketIO, so make sure this method is being called on the main thread. if it's not, make sure you martial the view updates back to the main thread.